Issue when loading Map within a popup or in a hidden react tab
I am working on an web app where I have to load a map (Here Maps) within a popup and also on a tab (react-bootstrap).
I am facing a couple of issues and I don't seem to find a solution for them.
In order to facilitate the explanation I have created an isolated example in codesandbox.
Tabs-Map-code-sandbox
See all files/components involved below. Note I have ignored imports and exports to keep it simple.
  const MainApp = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  const [key, setKey] = useState("home");
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);

  const goPopup = () => {
    setIsOpen(true);
  };

  return (
    <div style={{ margin: "10px" }}>
      <button
        style={{ marginTop: "10px", marginBottom: "10px" }}
        onClick={() => goPopup()}
      >
        Go popup
      </button>
      <Tabs
        id="controlled-tab-example"
        activeKey={key}
        onSelect={(k) => setKey(k)}
        className="mb-3"
      >
        <Tab eventKey="home" title="Home">
          <MapComponent />
        </Tab>
        <Tab eventKey="map" title="Map">
          <MapComponent />
        </Tab>
        <Tab eventKey="contact" title="Contact">
          Tab content for Contact
        </Tab>
      </Tabs>
      <ReactPortal
        handleClose={() => setIsOpen(false)}
        isOpen={isOpen}
        title={`Popup`}
      >
        <PopupTabs />
      </ReactPortal>
    </div>
  );
});

const MapComponent = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  const mapRef = useRef(null);
  const map = useRef(null);
  const platform = useRef(null);
  const [apikey, setApiKey] = useState("test");

  useEffect(() => {
    // Check if the map object has already been created
    if (!map.current) {
      // Create a platform object with the API key and useCIT option
      platform.current = new H.service.Platform({
        apikey,
        useHTTPS: true,
      });
      // Obtain the default map types from the platform object:
      const defaultLayers = platform.current.createDefaultLayers({
        pois: true,
      });

      console.log("Creating map");

      // Create a new map instance with the Tile layer, center and zoom level
      // Instantiate (and display) a map:
      const newMap = new H.Map(
        mapRef.current,
        defaultLayers.vector.normal.map,
        {
          zoom: 14,
          center: {
            lat: 64.144,
            lng: -21.94,
          },
        }
      );

      // Add panning and zooming behavior to the map
      const behavior = new H.mapevents.Behavior(
        new H.mapevents.MapEvents(newMap)
      );

      const ui = H.ui.UI.createDefault(newMap, defaultLayers);

      // Set the map object to the reference
      map.current = newMap;
    }
  }, []);

  return <div style={{ width: "400px", height: "400px" }} ref={mapRef} />;
});

const PopupTabs = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  return <MapComponent />;
});

const ReactPortal = ({ children, isOpen, title }) => {
  const [externalWindow, setExternalWindow] = useState(null);
  const [containerElement, setContainerElement] = useState(null);

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    if (isOpen) {
      const features =
        "width=800, height=500, left=300, top=200, menubar=0, resizable=1, scrollbars=1, status=0, toolbar=0";
      const externalWindow = window.open("", "", features);

      let containerElement = null;
      if (externalWindow) {
        containerElement = externalWindow.document.createElement("div");
        containerElement.setAttribute("width", "800px");
        containerElement.setAttribute("height", "500px");

        externalWindow.document.body.appendChild(containerElement);

        const stylesheets = Array.from(document.styleSheets);
        stylesheets.forEach((stylesheet) => {
          const css = stylesheet;
          if (stylesheet.href) {
            const newStyleElement = document.createElement("link");
            newStyleElement.rel = "stylesheet";
            newStyleElement.href = stylesheet.href;
            externalWindow.document.head.appendChild(newStyleElement);
          } else if (css && css.cssRules && css.cssRules.length > 0) {
            const newStyleElement = document.createElement("style");
            Array.from(css.cssRules).forEach((rule) => {
              newStyleElement.appendChild(
                document.createTextNode(rule.cssText)
              );
            });
            externalWindow.document.head.appendChild(newStyleElement);
          }
        });
        externalWindow.document.title = title;
        externalWindow.addEventListener("beforeunload", () => {
          setExternalWindow(null);
          setContainerElement(null);
        });
      }
      setExternalWindow(externalWindow);
      setContainerElement(containerElement);
    } else {
      setExternalWindow(null);
      setContainerElement(null);
    }

    return () => {
      if (externalWindow) {
        externalWindow.close();
      }
    };
  }, [isOpen]);

  if (containerElement === null) return null;

  return createPortal(children, containerElement);
};

export default ReactPortal;


Basically, the map component renders (tiles are shown) perfectly on the first tab (which is the one initially visible).
The issues start to exhibit on the second tab where only the map controls are loaded but the map tiles aren't instead it just shows an empty background.
The second issue which is more serious as it crashes the application is the one that tries to load the map on a popup using react portals.
The Map object needs a DOM element to render the map. As you can see I am using useRef hook to get the ref of a div element and then pass it down mapRef.current to Map object.
But it throws the following exception. InvalidArgumentError: H.Map (Argument #0).
What baffles me more is that outside the popup/or in the visible tab the map works as expected. So I think this is related to the readiness of the DOM in the popup or some type of timing issue which isn't easy to catch so any help would be much appreciated.
Note though on the example I have used a fake apiKey for here maps. (This should be enough for the example as we just want to load the tiles and there isn't any problem with that).
If you need any more clarification please let me know.
Thanks.

Please [edit] your question to contain a [mre] with all code required to understand the problem here within the question. Links to off-site code repositories are only applicable as supplementary data

Hi @Phil, check the link in the description it already contains a codesandbox showing both issues, thanks

I think you need to read my comment again

What do we expect to open with the portal, it seems to open a new tab

Why are we not relying on modal? The first part of the problem is because your component is not unmounting. So it can be done by adding these props to <Tabs unmountOnExit={true} mountOnEnter={true}

Basically you need to be 100% sure DOM is ready before rendering. and handle visibilty of map too.
Now it is rendering on second tab too.
Just Changing code to make sure

ReactPortal ensures the container is ready before rendering children
MainApp passing isVisible to Map Component to indicate when to initialize itself

If you want to understand code changes, just focus on the dependecies of effects and how these are used.

search keyword like isOpen and isVisible, how these are used

Main.jsx
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Tabs, Tab } from "react-bootstrap";
import MapComponent from "./map";
import ReactPortal from "./ReactPortal";

const MainApp = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  const [key, setKey] = useState("home");
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);

  const goPopup = () => {
    setIsOpen(true);
  };

  return (
    <div style={{ margin: "10px" }}>
      <button
        style={{ marginTop: "10px", marginBottom: "10px" }}
        onClick={() => goPopup()}
      >
        Go popup
      </button>
      <Tabs
        id="controlled-tab-example"
        activeKey={key}
        onSelect={(k) => setKey(k)}
        className="mb-3"
      >
        <Tab eventKey="home" title="Home">
          <MapComponent isVisible={key === "home"} />
        </Tab>
        <Tab eventKey="map" title="Map">
          <MapComponent isVisible={key === "map"} />
        </Tab>
        <Tab eventKey="contact" title="Contact">
          Tab content for Contact
        </Tab>
      </Tabs>
      <ReactPortal
        handleClose={() => setIsOpen(false)}
        isOpen={isOpen}
        title={`Popup`}
      >
        <MapComponent isVisible={isOpen} />
      </ReactPortal>
    </div>
  );
});

export default MainApp;

map.jsx
import React, { useRef, useEffect, useState } from "react";

const MapComponent = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  const mapRef = useRef(null);
  const map = useRef(null);
  const platform = useRef(null);
  const [apikey, setApiKey] = useState("test");

  useEffect(() => {
    if (mapRef.current && !map.current) {
      platform.current = new H.service.Platform({
        apikey,
        useHTTPS: true,
      });
      const defaultLayers = platform.current.createDefaultLayers({
        pois: true,
      });

      console.log("Creating map");

      const newMap = new H.Map(
        mapRef.current,
        defaultLayers.vector.normal.map,
        {
          zoom: 14,
          center: {
            lat: 64.144,
            lng: -21.94,
          },
        },
      );

      new H.mapevents.Behavior(new H.mapevents.MapEvents(newMap));
      H.ui.UI.createDefault(newMap, defaultLayers);

      map.current = newMap;
    }
  }, [apikey, mapRef]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (map.current) {
      map.current.getViewPort().resize();
    }
  }, [props.isVisible]);

  return <div style={{ width: "400px", height: "400px" }} ref={mapRef} />;
});

export default MapComponent;

ReactPortal.jsx
import React, { useState, useLayoutEffect } from 'react';
import { createPortal } from 'react-dom';

const ReactPortal = ({ children, isOpen, title, handleClose }) => {
  const [externalWindow, setExternalWindow] = useState(null);
  const [containerElement, setContainerElement] = useState(null);

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    if (isOpen) {
      const features =
        "width=800, height=500, left=300, top=200, menubar=0, resizable=1, scrollbars=1, status=0, toolbar=0";
      const externalWindow = window.open("", "", features);

      if (externalWindow) {
        const containerElement = document.createElement("div");
        containerElement.setAttribute("style", "width: 100%; height: 100%;");
        externalWindow.document.body.appendChild(containerElement);

        const stylesheets = Array.from(document.styleSheets);
        stylesheets.forEach((stylesheet) => {
          if (stylesheet.href) {
            const newStyleElement = document.createElement("link");
            newStyleElement.rel = "stylesheet";
            newStyleElement.href = stylesheet.href;
            externalWindow.document.head.appendChild(newStyleElement);
          } else if (stylesheet.cssRules) {
            const newStyleElement = document.createElement("style");
            Array.from(stylesheet.cssRules).forEach((rule) => {
              newStyleElement.appendChild(
                document.createTextNode(rule.cssText)
              );
            });
            externalWindow.document.head.appendChild(newStyleElement);
          }
        });

        externalWindow.document.title = title;
        externalWindow.addEventListener("beforeunload", handleClose);

        setExternalWindow(externalWindow);
        setContainerElement(containerElement);
      }
    } else {
      if (externalWindow) {
        externalWindow.close();
      }
      setExternalWindow(null);
      setContainerElement(null);
    }
  }, [isOpen, title, handleClose]);

  if (!containerElement) return null;

  return createPortal(children, containerElement);
};

export default ReactPortal;


